# Using ToList in GroupJoin cause "could not be translated" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to Join all the replies that fit the condition Replies.ReplyTo == Ticket.Id
in a reportInfo object. But when executing the request :

**Error message:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<HeskTicket>()
.Where(x => x.Status.Equals(3) && x.Custom7.Equals("Create") && x.FileCheck.Equals(False) && x.OrderDate < x.LastChange)
.Join(
inner: DbSet<HeskCategory>(),
outerKeySelector: ticket => ticket.Category,
innerKeySelector: category => category.Id,
resultSelector: (ticket, category) => new ReportInfo{
Ticket = ticket,
Category = category
}
)
.Join(
inner: DbSet<HeskUser>(),
outerKeySelector: ticket => ticket.Ticket.Owner,
innerKeySelector: user => user.Id,
resultSelector: (ticket, user) => new ReportInfo{
Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
Category = ticket.Category,
User = user
}
)
.LeftJoin(
inner: DbSet<HeskTemplateRelation>()
.Include(dr => dr.Placeholders)
.AsQueryable(),
outerKeySelector: ticket => ticket.Ticket.Custom6,
innerKeySelector: dataRelation => dataRelation.ActName,
resultSelector: (l, namelessParameter{0}) => new ReportInfo{
Ticket = l.Ticket,
Category = l.Category,
User = l.User,
TemplateRelation = namelessParameter{0}
}
)
.GroupJoin(
inner: DbSet<HeskReply>(),
outerKeySelector: ticket => ticket.Ticket.Id,
innerKeySelector: replies => replies.Replyto,
resultSelector: (ticket, replies) => new ReportInfo{
Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
Category = ticket.Category,
User = ticket.User,
TemplateRelation = ticket.TemplateRelation,
Replies = replies
.ToList()
})
```

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
> be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
> a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.c om/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information.

## ReportInfo

```
public class ReportInfo
    {
        public HeskTicket Ticket { get; set; }
        public HeskCategory Category { get; set; }
        public HeskTemplateRelation TemplateRelation { get; set; }
        public HeskUser User { get; set; }
        public List<HeskReply> Replies { get; set; }
    }
```

## Here is my Join Expression:

```
 public async Task<List<ReportInfo>> GetInfoForReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var joinedData = await _mariaDbContext.HeskTickets.Where(x =>
                    x.Status.Equals(SearchConstants.Closed) &&
                    x.Custom7.Equals(SearchConstants.Required) &&
                    x.FileCheck.Equals(false) &&
                    x.OrderDate < x.LastChange)
                .Join(
                    _mariaDbContext.HeskCategories,
                    ticket => ticket.Category,
                    category => category.Id,
                    (ticket, category) => new ReportInfo()
                    {
                        Ticket = ticket,
                        Category = category
                    })
                .Join(
                    _mariaDbContext.HeskUsers,
                    ticket => ticket.Ticket.Owner,
                    user => user.Id,
                    (ticket, user) => new ReportInfo()
                    {
                        Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
                        Category = ticket.Category,
                        User = user
                    })
                .LeftJoin(_mariaDbContext.HeskTemplateRelation.Include(dr => dr.Placeholders),
                    ticket => ticket.Ticket.Custom6,
                    dataRelation => dataRelation.ActName,
                    (ticket, dataRelation) => new ReportInfo()
                    {
                        Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
                        Category = ticket.Category,
                        User = ticket.User,
                        TemplateRelation = dataRelation
                    })
                .GroupJoin(
                    _mariaDbContext.HeskReplies,
                ticket => ticket.Ticket.Id,
                    replies => replies.Replyto,
                    (ticket, replies) => new ReportInfo()
                        {
                            Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
                            Category = ticket.Category,
                            User = ticket.User,
                            TemplateRelation = ticket.TemplateRelation,
                            Replies = replies.ToList()
                        }
                    )
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            return joinedData;
        }
```

All code before GroupJoin works correctly.

Expectig reportInfo object with list of replies that equal ticket id. Ive tried join but it cause creating many copies that contain 1 reply instead list of replies.

Comment: sry,  translator changed something superfluous :D

Comment: Why you think that EF translates GroupJoin with ToList()?... See Complex Query Operators topic of official documentation

Comment: Have you tried query syntax? I cannot understand what you are trying to retrieve. `LeftJoin` is also unknown extension.